# typo3 error while installing, no error log available

Tags: typo3

while installing typo3 I faced some issues and now I'm stuck..

I just get the error page

"Oops, an error occurred!"

What's the best way to find the error?

Comment: Can you login in the backend? Maybe TYPO3 log there can help. If you don't have more info's all stays in the dark.

Comment: Sounds like the broken installation, check install tool area and enable all the error logs.

Comment: I solved it by enabling debug mode via install tool

Answer (score 3):

Things you could do:

- open `typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php` and set `displayErrors` to 1 in the `SYS` section
- have a look in the TYPO3 log file (see below)
- go to domain.tld/typo3/install or domain.tld/typo3/install.php and check for errors there

Which TYPO3 version do you use? If it's TYPO3 8.7 or higher, you can find the error log in `typo3temp/var/logs`. In older versions, it's just `typo3temp/logs`.